# Android phone call activity launch race condition

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to avoid the situation where my application is launched right after a phone call is received on the device.

The problem with this situation is that the toolbar and the bar on the bottom are disabled and the phone call is still ringing in the background but the user cannot access it like he is used to.

The scenario can be easily reproduced by receiving a phone call and then launching an application from the computer.

Answer (score 0):

I afraid that there is nothing to do about the situation you described.

also seems like this problem have nothing to do with a specific version of android, but as a specific behavior of the default phone call app which pre- installed on the Nexus 5 with android 4.4.x firmware.

as I saw across different devices with different android versions - I notices this behavior only on Nexus with android 4.4.x  .  they probably locks (with their own system permission) the status bar, and dismiss it back only when phone call activity is destroyed, instead of when it been paused.

if this behavior is problematic for you, you can work around the issue - by listening to phone state broadcast changes, and maybe decide to prevent your activity from being launch in case that currently the phone is ringing

good luck